# Why use st_union after st_combine with sf?

Tags: r, sf, union, combine, st-difference

The [documentation](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_combine.html) of the `st_union` function of `sf` is not clear (for me!) on one point: what are the action and result of the function when applied to an `sfc` with a single feature, with the parameter `by_feature=FALSE` (default)? It seems that, according to the text of the documentation, nothing should happen and that the value returned should be the same as the one-feature `sfc` provided.

I ask this question because it is rather common to find proposals, advice for chaining `st_union` to `st_combine`, especially in the context of the use of `st_difference` (see the `sf` manual, at `geos_binary_ops`, or `?st_intersection`):

the use of `st_difference(SF1,st_union(st_combine(SF2)))` is proposed.

Two questions in order to understand:

- Because `st_combine` returns a single-feature `sfc`, how could `st_union` have any effect on such an object?
- Is there any simple case, any example, where `st_union`, with `by_feature=FALSE`, applied to a single `sfc` has any effect?

Extract of the documentation of `st_union`:

> If `st_union` is called with a single argument, x, and by_feature is FALSE all geometries are unioned together and an `sfg` or single-geometry `sfc` object is returned. If `by_feature` is TRUE each feature geometry is unioned. This can for instance be used to resolve internal boundaries after polygons were combined using `st_combine`.

Answer (score 4):

I might not have the correct language to exactly explain this, but I just discovered a case where using `sf::st_combine` before calling `sf::st_union` made a big difference to me.

I was using `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarise` to group an `sf` tibble by a certain variable and then union each group to a single sf object:

```
sf_tibble %>%
  dplyr::group_by(area) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise()
```

However, what I ended up with was *multipolygon* geometries, which is fine, but it meant that when I plotted my shapes with text labels, I ended up with multiple text labels for each area. I only wanted a single text label.

Then I tried using `st_combine` first, then `st_union`, and this solved my issue. I now only get single text labels for each area. To be explicit:

```
sf_tibble %>%
  dplyr::group_by(area) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(geometry, ~ sf::st_combine(.)), .groups = "keep") %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(geometry, ~ sf::st_union(.)), .groups = "drop")
```

[It may be that a plain `dplyr::summarise()` is fine for one of those lines, and I'm not sure how important the `.groups` bits are.]

(Edit:

```
sf_tibble %>%
  dplyr::group_by(area) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(geometry, ~ sf::st_combine(.)), .groups = "keep") %>%
  # dplyr::summarise(across(geometry, ~ sf::st_union(.)), .groups = "drop")
  dplyr::summarise()
```

seems to have the same effect as the code in the previous block.)

I realised that I might need to do this when [I read that](https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2021/03/15/simplifying-geospatial-features-in-r-with-sf-and-rmapshaper/) `st_union`

> can be used to join overlapping and adjacent features

My areas were *not* all comprised of overlapping and adjacent features - some of them were coastal areas with separate islands. So then I realised that I maybe needed to combine the areas first, before unioning.